# Make menu page link inaccessible or disabled

Tags: plugins, admin-menu

I want to disable/hide the menu pages for users other than admin. I am able to successfully do it with the following logic. But the menu pages appear through the url.

```
<?php 
function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    remove_menu_page( $menu_slug );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
?>
```

Is there a way to disable the menu pages through the url also?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that use the following function:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );

function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        $menu = array(
            'edit.php',
            'edit-comments.php'
            );
        foreach ( $menu as $main ) {
            remove_menu_page( $main );
        }
        if ( in_array( $pagenow, $menu, true ) && ( !isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) || isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'post' ) ) {
            wp_die( 'Access denied...' );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

This will execute the function only if the user is **not** an admin. Where you see `edit.php` and `edit-comments.php`, you can replace and add more menu slug that you want to hide. Make sure you add a `,` after each one except for the last one.

Comment: when i login as editor and type the url `myblog/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page`, the page appears. I want to make it inaccessible through the url too.

Comment: Updated the answer, now when the user tries to visit the page, it gives them an "access denied..." message

Comment: Great. Be sure to upvote this answer and click the green check mark to let the community know that this question is **solved**. Thanks